# Emails Templates

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, html-email

Im developing a app that will be sending a lot emails for the users, the structure of the email is basically the same(header, footer), what it changes is the content. There are 30 different emails, that the only thing it changes is the content. Since i dont whant to create 30 views i was thinking in a better way. I was thinking in using one view and the content was passed in a controller. The problem is passing the data in the controller, it doesnt look right passing html (tables, etc) in the controller, since im working in a MVC pattern. Can someone give any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Structure the email template in a way that has same structure for every email. Preferably use [these](https://github.com/mailgun/transactional-email-templates) templates.

If your structure (in content) for emails changes dramatically, then you should prefer multiple templates, say 3.

Now pass data from the controller, be it title (that appears in  tag) or a slogan that may appear in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for **a build system** for creating a series of email templates with common parts.

I've used [Lee Munroe's Grunt Email Workflow](https://github.com/leemunroe/grunt-email-workflow) to create a series of transactional emails. You can set up shared partials (header, footer, etc.) and just create small files for each individual email. If also comes with lots of other niceties (SASS, Live Preview/Reload, Litmus Integration), but this should address your templating concerns.

[image]